# Como criar filtros default com entity framework 6?

Tags: entity-framework-6, filtro

Tenho um campo Excluido em varias classes e quando vou fazer o meu select sempre tenho que impor essa condição na consulta, existe alguma forma de fazer o filtro de uma forma implícita? lembrando que é EF 6.

```
var consulta = this.Contexto.Set<ClienteIdRaiz>().AsQueryable();
var totalRegistros = 0;

consulta = consulta.Where(x => !x.Excluido);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Entity Framework 6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/)

O [Entity Framework 6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/) não tem o recurso próprio para fazer [Global Query Filter](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/wiki/EF-Query-Filter-%7C-Entity-Framework-Dynamic-Instance-and-Global-Filters#ef-query-filter-global), mas, com a adição dos pacotes via [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/):

- [Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EF6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EF6/)
- [Z.EntityFramework.Plus.QueryIncludeFilter.EF6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Z.EntityFramework.Plus.QueryIncludeFilter.EF6/)

tem a adição de recursos sobre o [Entity Framework 6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/) e um deles é disponibilizar um filtro global em sua `SQL` de forma implícita.

Após instalação dos dois pacotes e a configuração da sua classe faça a adição de uma linha dentro do `construtor` da classe que herda do `DbContext`. Um cenário seria recuperar todas as pessoas com o campo `Ativo = 1`, ***exemplo***:

```cs
public DatabaseContext()
        :base(ConnStr)
{
    Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(null);
    QueryFilterManager.Filter<People>(x => x.Where(a => a.Active == true));
}
```

**ou**

chame o método de extensão `Filter<>`, ***exemplo***:

```cs
public DatabaseContext()
            :base(ConnStr)
{
    Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(null);            
    this.Filter<People>(x => x.Where(a => a.Active));
}
```

além dos filtros esse fica padrão em toda a aplicação, pelo nome já diz [Global Query Filter](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/wiki/EF-Query-Filter-%7C-Entity-Framework-Dynamic-Instance-and-Global-Filters#ef-query-filter-global). Se algum momento na aplicação precisar que esse filtro não seja chamada utilize o método `AsNoFilter()`, ***exemplo***:

```cs
db.People.AsNoFilter().ToList();
```

que o filtro não será adicionado na `SQL`.

Exemplo minimo completo:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using Z.EntityFramework.Plus;

namespace ConsoleApp41.Models
{
    public class People
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
    }

    public class DatabaseContext: DbContext
    {
        protected const string ConnStr = "Connect_Strings";
        public DatabaseContext()
            :base(ConnStr)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(null);
            QueryFilterManager.Filter<People>(x => x.Where(a => a.Active == true));
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<People>()
                .ToTable("People");

            modelBuilder.Entity<People>()
                .HasKey(X => X.Id)
                .Property(x => x.Id)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
                .IsRequired();

            modelBuilder.Entity<People>()
                .Property(x => x.Name)
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsRequired();

            modelBuilder.Entity<People>()
                .Property(x => x.Active)
                .IsRequired();

        }

        public DbSet<People> People { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[Na documentação tem uma variedade de filtros](http://EF%20Query%20Filter%20%7C%20Entity%20Framework%20Dynamic%20Instance%20and%20Global%20Filters), mas, sobre a sua duvida o que está na resposta é o ideal para o seu desenvolvimento.

---

- [Entity Framework Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/)

Esse recurso não está presente no [Entity Framework 6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/), mas, no [Entity Framework Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/) já existe tal recurso com o nome de [Global Query Filters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters), como configurar?

No método `OnModelCreating`, adicione uma linha como exemplo abaixo:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<People>().HasQueryFilter(p => p.Active);
    //
}
```

tem o mesmo efeito do exemplo do pacote instalado na versão ***6*** e também tem como desabilitar utilizando o método `IgnoreQueryFilters()`, exemplo:

```cs
var result  = db.People.IgnoreQueryFilters().ToList();
```

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EF6 - Global Query Filter](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/wiki/EF-Query-Filter-%7C-Entity-Framework-Dynamic-Instance-and-Global-Filters#ef-query-filter-global)
- [Instalação - Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EF6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EF6/)
- [Instalação - Z.EntityFramework.Plus.QueryIncludeFilter.EF6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Z.EntityFramework.Plus.QueryIncludeFilter.EF6/)
- [Entity Framework Core - Global Query Filters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters)

Comment: Será que tem como implementar com um tipo genérico ?